# VLOOKUP in VBA Excel VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VLOOKUP macro that prompts the user to select cells and ranges.

Basically I want to look up a cell value in one tab against a range in another tab and return a column the user selects.

So...This is what I want...

```
VLOOKUP(""USER SELECT LOOKUP value", "USER SELECT TABLE ARRAY", "USER SELECT COL INDEX NUM", FALSE)
```

I have this so far but nothing returns when the macro finishes running...

```
Subject = Application.Input box("select Subject to be looked up")
Sheet = Application.Input box("select tab/range")

          Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""Subject"",""Sheet"",3,False)"

end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pull the variables out of the quotes and concatenate using `&`.

Also you want to make them ranges and use their address in the formula:

```
Dim subject As Range
Dim sheet As Range
Dim clm as long
Set subject = Application.InputBox(prompt:="select Subject to be looked up", Type:=8)
Set sheet = Application.InputBox(prompt:="select tab/range", Type:=8)
clm = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Relative Column Reference", Type:=1)
'Change the range to the cell into which you want the formula placed.
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Subject.Address(0,0) & "," & sheet.Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & "," & clm & ",False)"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help! I tried using this but it throws me an error...Runtime 91 object variable with block variable not set

Comment: @Ben sorry my bad.  See edit.  You may need to refresh the page.  If it ends up working please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: That's OK. Yeah I realized after I sent my comment that it wasn't Set so I set them but it still does not return a value, just a blank cell with no formula.

Comment: I just copied your code.  With formula you need to specify the range into which it will be sent.  I assumed, wrongly, that `Formula` was a string variable and you were then using that string.  see edit.

Comment: Ah that worked a treat! Just a couple of things though, can we build into this a way that the subject.address is not $A$1? I need it unlocked. Also, with the ",3,false...can we make the 3 manually entered also? So the user specifies what the column index number to be returned is? I know there is a way to add a freetext prompt box and the returned value in the formula is whatever the user entered...be it a 2, 3, 4 or even 12...is it possible?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! Perfect